# Cloudfront security headers causes CORS issues

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have two different Vue.JS apps deployed to AWS S3 + Cloudfront. The first has the domain set up in Route53, while the second has the domain set up in Google's domain service.

Both of the apps works completely fine. Recently I tried using the cloudfront predefined security headers under the "behavior" settings:

[image]

The header policy has all of the following:

[image]

The first app (with the domain configured in Route53) continues to work perfectly fine, but for the second app I started getting CORS issues.

[image]

This boggles the mind a little bit, because I'm getting CORS errors from within the same domain.

[image]

Comment: I think it's complaining about your scripts not having the right MIME type (expects `application/javascript`). Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67928269

Comment: @LouisWaweru - This is a Vue.JS single page application with no manually linked js files - the whole thing compiles into an `index.html` file and a bunch of js and css files when it's built, all handled by the vue CLI. Inspecting the `index.html` file shows that the generated script files are added with: `<script src="/js/app.ecba88eb.js"></script>`. Just to be sure, I manually added `type="application/javascript"` and updated S3 and invalidated the cloudfront cache, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: @LouisWaweru - wait, I only read your message before and somehow missed the link you provided. There is hope, I am attempting this now.

Comment: @LouisWaweru yes that's it, it works, unbelievable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's complaining about your scripts not having the right MIME type (expects application/javascript). Does this help?

> manually change the system-defined content-type in the S3 console for the individual js objects from text/plain to application/javascript, then make sure the cache was invalidated and refreshed

*source: [schquestionasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926642/cloudfront-serving-javascript-files-as-mime-type-of-text-plain/67928269#67928269)*